# most efficient way to randomly null out values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10, 10)) * 2,
                  list('abcdefghij'), list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df
```

[image]

***How can I nullify ~20% of these values at random?***

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to generate a [mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p=[.2,.8])

df.mask(mask)
```

---

In one line:

```
df.mask(np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p=[.2,.8]))
```

Speed tested using `timeit` at ~770μs:

```
>>> python -m timeit -n 10000 
        -s "import pandas as pd;import numpy as np;df=pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10,10))*2)"
        "df.mask(np.random.choice([True,False], size=df.shape, p=[.2,.8]))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 770 usec per loop
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer.  To make it more general, you might want to use `size=df.shape` instead of hard coding it in.

Comment: Thanks @root!  Added to the answer.

Comment: I originally thunk up something very similar.  This is a much more elegant answer.  I'd take root's suggestion one step further, not much better, but every bit helps.  use `df.values.shape`

Comment: Thanks!  I must be missing something - how does `df.values.shape` improve on `df.shape`?  It doesn't appear to do better when I time test it.  Does it scale better?

Comment: if i want to choose the columns to indroduce nan values and choose the exact percent for each column, how do i do that ?

Comment: @lb-D, this is a reasonable question, but it goes beyond what OP asked for, so I'd recommend asking that as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), where the fraction you want to sample is the fraction of non-null values you want in the resulting frame (i.e. one minus the fraction of null values).

```
df = df.stack().sample(frac=0.8).unstack()
```

The resulting output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
a  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0
b  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
c  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0
d  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
e  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
f  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
g  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
h  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
i  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0
j  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

EDIT:

Depending on how small your sample is, the method above could cause you to lose rows/columns if they become all `NaN`.  If this is not desired, the workaround would be to add a [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) at the end:

```
df = df.stack().sample(frac=0.8).unstack().reindex(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```